# Selecting 3 Different Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table named `rsales`, `rreturn`, `productlist`.  Table `rsales` and `rreturn` has `total` *column*. My aim is, I want to sum all `total` values from `rsales` and `total` value from `rreturn` table and select specific value only from `productlist` table.

Let say, for example, I have this data from `productlist` table:

```
id | pcode | pname | pdesc | 
1  |  222  | 33uf  |  10v  |
```

data from `rsales` table:

```
id | total | pcode |
1  |  200  | 222   |
2  |  200  | 222   |
```

data from `rreturn` table:

```
id | total | pcode |
1  |  50   | 222   |
2  |  20   | 222   |
```

the **output** must be something like this:

```
   id | pcode | pname | pdesc | total 
   1  |  222  | 33uf  |  10v  |  470
```

My question is this: I want to sum all `total` values from `rsales` and `rreturn` table and select all values from `productlist`. I have this following code below and runs very well. But it can only sum total value from `rsales` table, or rather, it can only sum value from one single table.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
    productlist.*, 
    SUM(rsales.total) as total, 
        SUM(rsales.vatable_sales) as vatable_sales, 
    SUM(rsales.vats) as vats,
     SUM(rsales.discount) as discount

FROM productlist
LEFT JOIN rsales ON rsales.pcode = productlist.pcode
GROUP BY pcode
ORDER BY total ASC");
```

Comment: Please show us sample data as well.

Comment: And desired output for that data.

Comment: i have provided already an example sir

Answer (score 1):

You are not very explicit about what doesn't work for you. Are you getting results, but the numbers are not what you are expecting? Well, say you have three sales and two returns, then you get six records by joining all tables. Thus you double your sales and triple your returns.

You can join aggregations instead, for one solution:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
    productlist.*, 
    sumsales.sum_total + sumreturns.sum_total as total, 
    sumsales.sum_vatable_sales as vatable_sales, 
    sumsales.sum_vats as vats,
    sumsales.sum_discount as discount
    FROM productlist
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT pcode, SUM(total) as sum_total, SUM(vatable_sales) as sum_vatable_sales, SUM(vats) as sum_vats, SUM(discount) as sum_discount
      FROM rsales
      GROUP BY pcode
    ) AS sumsales ON sumsales.pcode = productlist.pcode
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT pcode, SUM(total) as sum_total 
      FROM rreturn 
      GROUP BY pcode
    ) AS sumreturns ON sumreturns.pcode = productlist.pcode
    ORDER BY total ASC");
```